# onchange update state in map loop [react]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this array of data like blow:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "answers": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "text": "",
        "is_answer": false
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "text": "",
        "is_answer": false
      }
    ],
    "question_type": "multichoice"
  }
]
```

and I loop answers and I want to have input for each item and onChage event for inputs.

```
    {question.answers &&
      question.answers.map((answer) => (
        <div>
          <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="test" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              id="input-with-icon-grid"
              label="Answer"
         
              onChange={(event) =>
                answerText(event)
              }
              value={text}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
```

but my onChange doesn't work properly.

```
const answerText = (event) => {
  setText(event.target.value);

}
```

every time I change input text just update on letter and remove the rest.

Comment: can you show full code? where you have defined state and all?

Comment: What do you use the `text` variable that you set with `setText`?

Comment: You pass in `answer.id` and `question.id` into `answerText` but you don't use them, that should give you a clue.